# Local HTML does not open on Android

Tags: android, html, webview, android-studio

I have a Android Studio project, this project should have local HTML files.
I don't know if I understand the files structure, or the problem is another.

The file is not opened. Only display this error:

[image]

File Structure:

[image]

Code:

```
<WebView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/webViewRevistas"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />



public class revistas extends ActionBarActivity {

private WebView webViewRevistas;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_revistas);

    WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webViewRevistas);
    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.loadUrl("file:///assets/index.html");
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You recently added this file? Then you should uninstall your app and again install fresh built

Comment: Yes, I added recently. I removed this app from my device and tryed again. Same error :(

Comment: Also change `file:///assets/` to `file:///android_asset/`

Comment: Don't work. Should be like this: "file:///android_asset/assets/index.html"? But I created the assets directory, is not default

Answer (score 3):

The path is wrong.

It's not

```
file:///assets/...
```

but:

```
file:///android_asset/...
```

Comment: So, should be like this: `"file:///android_asset/assets/index.html"`? But I created the `assets` directory, is not default.

Comment: It's like `file:///android_asset/index.html`

Comment: As @MD pointed out, it's just `file:///android_asset/index.html`. It doesn't matter that **you** created the folder. Simply replace `assets` with `android_asset` in your path here: `mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");`.

Comment: Don't work. Same message: "The webpage at `file:///android_asset/index.html` could not be loaded becouse: ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND"

Comment: Also try removing the part: `mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {`... (This: `public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {` is expecting an url to be passed)

Comment: Very strange... it works in all my projects (I use this as a Help system).

Comment: Your files (.html) are in root directory (app)? Or inside another, like my structure?

Comment: Make sure that the assets folder is **on the root level of your project folder structure** (in Eclipse). Or the equivalent path in Android Studio. **Or it won't be found**

Answer (score 0):

to fix this create a folder in "main" called "android_asset" and also create another folder called "assets" and place your html file in assets and call using this mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/YOUR HTML FILE.html");

I had the same problem and even though I dont call mWebView.loadUrl("file:///assets/YOUR HTML FILE.html"); it still some how works. which i find strange because thats where the html actually is!

You may have to duplicate your htmls for older android versions and place in android_asset also.

So again your folders should look like this main/android_assets/assets/YOUR HTML.html and main/assets/ and call with mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/YOUR HTML FILE.html");

Heres how my oncreate looks.

private WebView mWebView;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
    // Enable Javascript
    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");

}
```