# html(static pages) pages are not opening in Android5 devices.

Tags: android

html(static pages) pages are not opening in Android5 devices while pages are opening in lower version of Android like 4.2, 4.4 etc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Local HTML does not open on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28275788/local-html-does-not-open-on-android)

Comment: If above Link not works then post your code .

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) demonstrating your problem.

Comment: I have created an application which is having some html pages and some online services where user logs in and checks his details. My issue is when user opens html pages in his android lollipop device pages dont open and just show waiting symbol while, these pages are easily opened in android4.2 and android4.4 devices. I am not getting any solution for my problem please comment

Comment: I got the issue resolved, I was using jquery version 1.3.0, after replacing the said version by 1.4.5 my issue got resolved. Thanks everyone